# What is the difference between TCCR1A and TCCR1B

Tags: atmega, datasheet, timer, register

I had an error in the configuration of PWM for the atmega8 because I didn't set my register properly. But I thought that Timer 1 **is** timer 1, no matter is TCCR1A or TCCR1B. Why can I set **all** the timer 1 using only TCCR1A like so:

```
TCCR1A  = ((1 << COM1A1) | (1 << COM1A0) (1 << CS11) | (1 << WGM13) );
```

[Datasheet](http://www.atmel.ca/Images/Atmel-2486-8-bit-AVR-microcontroller-ATmega8_L_datasheet.pdf)

EDIT : I was confused about the fact that TCCR1A and TCCR1B are different registers which are set for the same timer.

Comment: Your questions is unclear to me. Please write more detailed and explain better. Also the specific atmega chip and a link to the datasheet is always a good thing to add to the question.

Comment: I did my best to explain it above.
Basically, why I cannot do PWM like this : TCCR1A  = ((1 << COM1A1) | (1 << COM1A0) (1 << CS11) | (1 << WGM13) );

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all I think you missed a `|` symbol:

```
TCCR1A  = ((1 << COM1A1) | (1 << COM1A0) (1 << CS11) | (1 << WGM13) );

TCCR1A  = ((1 << COM1A1) | (1 << COM1A0) | (1 << CS11) | (1 << WGM13) );
```

Second:

- Bits `COM1A1` and `COM1A0`  are in register `TCCR1A`
- Bits `CS11` and `WGM13` are in `TCCR1B`

`TCCR1A` and `TCCR1B` are different registers, but they work on the same timer, timer1. They configure different behavior and are located in separate registers, simply because all the bits don't fit in a single byte.

Notice that `COM1A1` is simply an alias for the number `7`, so is `COM1A0` alias for number `6`, `WGM13` is an alias for number `4` and `CS11` for `1`. It is up to you, the user, to check if you are writing the correct bits in the correct registers. The compiler does *not* check this for you.

For example the following three lines will have the same resulting assembly code:

```
TCCR1A = ( 1 << COM1A1 );
TCCR1A = ( 1 << PB7 );
TCCR1A = ( 1 << ICNC1 );
```

**All three lines** will result in the following identical two assembly instructions:

```
ldi r24, 0x80
out 0x2F, r24
```

`TCCR1(A|B)` **cannot** be accessed as a single 16 bit register like `TCNT1(H|L)` can.

Comment: Wow,thanks, this was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing setting the PWM output pin Data Direction Register to output (DDRx) and a value have to be set in the ICR1.

**From the data sheet about DDR:**

*"If one or both of the
COM1B1:0 bit are written to one, the OC1B output overrides the normal port functionality of the
I/O pin it is connected to. However, note that the Data Direction Register (DDR) bit corresponding
to the OC1A or OC1B pin must be set in order to enable the output driver."*

So you have to set the DDR when though setting the COM1A1 and COM1A0 bits.

**From the data sheet about counting:**

*"In phase and frequency correct PWM mode the counter is incremented until the counter value
matches the value in ICR1 (WGM13:0 = 8)"*

This means that ICR1 register in your case will be the value you have to adjust since you set WGM13 only:

[image: ICR1 WGM13]